# Excel Vlookup VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I need to add Invoice as a Test and then V lookup formula should run

For example :="invoice"&" "&VLOOKUP(H3,FBL5N!D:G,4,0)
this formula i need to covert to Macro's

Let me know how to fix i tried my VBA formula as:

```
On Error Resume Next
For i = 3 To lastrow_d
     ws_zfi.Range("AY3:AY" & lastrow_d) = "invoice" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws_zfi.Range("H3:H" & lastrow_d), ws_fbl5n.Range("D1:G" & lastrow_d), 4, 0)
 Next i
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  My first guess is *expected end* and you need to fix your quotations.  Related to your example, you can put the space in with invoice, e.g., "invoice " instead of needing the other &.

Comment: You're passing a range of cells (potentially many) as the first parameter of a `VLOOKUP`, when it would be expecting a value/string - `ws_zfi.Range("H3:H" & lastrow_d)`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without seeing the source tables but I *think* you want the following:

```
For i = 3 To lastrow_d
    ws_zfi.Range("AY" & i) = "invoice" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws_zfi.Range("H" & i), ws_fbl5n.Range("D1:G" & lastrow_d), 4, 0)
Next i
```